# NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey not enabled - Migrating form NSPersistentContainter to NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have a core data legacy implementation which utilizes NSPersistentContainer.
When I started the project I had NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey = false.

Now I want to switch to Core Data + CloudKit.
Worrying about data loss I

1. created a project with NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey is false that uses NSPersistentContainer
2. created some records (A, B)
3. set NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey = true (still using NSPersistentContainer)
4. created some records (C, D)
5. Changed NSPersistentContainer to NSPersistentCloudKitContainer and enabled Remote and CloudKit capabilities
6. Sync

What happened is exactly what I worried about.
A and B got wiped while C and D remain...

My current understating is that in order to ensure that syncing continues to work even when offline or when cloud sync is disabled, you need to set NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey to true. Otherwise sync may not work. Is this understanding correct?

If so, is there a way to turn on NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey for those records created while NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey is false?

How would one go about migrating from NSPersistentContainer with NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey is false to NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey is true?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!